# Get Author's name of a Tweet

Tags: c#, wpf, twitterizer

I want to display a tweet as it is shown in the [url=https://dev.twitter.com/terms/display-guidelines]Display Guideline[/url]. For that, I need to get the name of the author of the tweet.
 I don't have this info in the TwitterSearchResult:

```
 TwitterResponse<TwitterSearchResultCollection> searchResult = TwitterSearch.Search(hashtag, options);
 _tweets = searchResult.ResponseObject;
```

So I tried that :

```
OptionalProperties option = new OptionalProperties();
TwitterResponse<TwitterUser> user = TwitterUser.Show(_tweets[0].FromUserScreenName, option );
```

But I have an error :

> Rate limit exceeded. Clients may not make more than 150 requests per
>   hour.

So I tried with tokens, without options, with UserID etc...without success :/

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Rate limit exceeded. Clients may not make more than 150 requests per hour.

Means that there have been [too many calls to twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting) from your IP address.

You'll have to wait.